# Display only one result from "get_the_category_list"

Tags: categories, list

I'd like `get_the_category_list` to only display one or two categories instead of **all** the categories associated with the post. Haven't been able to find any results.

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick idea would be to pass some simple separator like comma and cut from the start of result till it.

But I think that if you want better control on output it would make more sense to use level deeper `get_the_category()` function and build markup yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This worked. Found in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit `get_the_category` to any number you can use `break;`

For example if you want to limit echoing a category + link to show say only 5 categories.

```
     $i = 0;
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'"> | ' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
        if (++$i == 5) break;
      }
```